# Was there ever a reason for the removed He-Man reference in the German dub?

Tags: ghostbusters-2

During the opening, it's shown that the Ghostbusters now appear at children parties:
[image: The Ghostbusters visiting a children party.]

However, as we quickly learn, the kids are all but eager to meet the former heroes that saved the city 5 years ago. Instead, they loudly claim they'd "gonna call" He-Man.

Except in the German dubbed version, where the whole scene plays pretty much identical, also their comments etc. are translated pretty much 1:1, except one major detail: The kids demand "Muscle Man" rather than He-Man. Note that this is a completely English name/made up reference and not just a case of "they translated a proper name".

**He-Man** at the time was a very well established and widely known toy line and cartoon show, yet for some to me unknown reason the studio tasked with dubbing – Berliner Synchron – or some of those responsible for the German release decided to go with this change.

**Was there ever some elusive official explanation on what happened?** Or was it just some mistake? Fearing licensing issues? Trying to explain the figure to an older audience (that might not understand the English name either way)?

Comment: Translation is tricky business and often completely dependent on the translators knowledge of things....it‘s difficult to know exactly why it was changed...could be anything from the translator didn‘t know heman, thought germans wouldn‘t know heman, or didn‘t care. German translations for a time were hilariously bad for a while aswell....

Comment: Yes, Star Trek fans from Germany have commented about how bad the Germans dubbing of TOS was.